# jQuery .click for multiple elements with same class

Tags: jquery, onclick, click

I have a small piece of jQuery that I need a bit of help with.  Here's what I have:

jQuery:

```
jQuery(".disableUser").click(function() {
    jQuery(".enableUser").show()
    jQuery(".disableUser").hide();
});

jQuery(".enableUser").click(function() {
    jQuery(".disableUser").show()
    jQuery(".enableUser").hide();
});
```

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><span class="disableUser">Disable this user</span><span class="enableUser">Enable this user</span></td>
</tr>
```

`.enableUser` is set to `display:none` as default.

As you can see, it is simply hiding or showing an element.  My issue is that there are rows in a table, with each row having the same two elements.  When I click one row's element it hides or shows all the row's element.  I only want it to affect the specific element I am clicking on and not all elements with the same class.  I have tried the info found here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/click-once-and-unbind/, but I am not sure if I am understanding it or using it correctly.

Comment: post relevant html too, you need to target specific elements regarding the one clicked

Comment: Thanks, I added the basic html of the row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to find the `.enableUser` and `.disableUser` of the current row. `this` will refer to the clicked element and from there you can traverse the DOM and find the right elements:

```
jQuery(".disableUser").click(function() {
    jQuery(this).hide().closest("tr").find(".enableUser").show();
});
```

Have a look at the documentation for [`.closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [`.find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) for more information. You might also want to read more about [event handling](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/).

Comment: @roasted: Of course! Just tweaked it a little since I don't know if both elements are in the same cell. Thanks!

Comment: Please see above, I added the basic HTML I will be using.  Thanks.

Comment: Just commented below on roasted's answer.  Both answers work exactly how I wanted it to.  Which way is the preferred way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(".disableUser").click(function() {
    jQuery(this).hide().siblings('.enableUser').show();
});

jQuery(".enableUser").click(function() {
    jQuery(this).hide().siblings('.disableUser').show();
});
```

Comment: Both of these answers work exactly how I wanted it to.  Which answer is the preferred way of doing it?

Comment: This one is a little bit optimized but nothing you'll never notice so just choose the one which seems more readable for you and upvote both answers :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm upvoting it for sure.  Felix posted his first, so I'll accept his.  I'm actually going to use your answer though.  Thanks again.